# AngularJS Karma Jasmine cannot call module

Tags: angularjs

I would like to start unit testing my AngularJS app. I installed and configured Karma but I cannot use the function module.

**error message:**

First Test encountered a declaration exception FAILED
    TypeError: Property 'module' of object [object Object] is not a function
        at null. (C:/dev/tubs-web-reporting/TubsReporting.Web/app/test/controller.test.js:3:16)
        at C:/dev/tubs-web-reporting/TubsReporting.Web/app/test/controller.test.js:1:1

**app.js:**

```
angular.module('tufreport', ['tufreport.filters', 'tufreport.services', 'tufreport.directives', 'tufreport.controllers',
     'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.directives', 'ui.bootstrap'
```

**controller.test.js:**

```
describe('First Test', function(){
    beforeEach(module('tufreport'));
});
```

**karma.unit.conf.js:**

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Mon Mar 03 2014 14:14:15 GMT+1100 (Central Pacific Standard Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '.',


    // frameworks to use
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
     'Scripts/angular.js',
     'Scripts/angular-mocks.js',
     'Scripts/angular-*.js',
     'Scripts/leaflet.js',
     'app/js/app.js',
     'app/js/services.js',
     'app/js/filters.js',
     'app/js/directives.js',
     'app/js/controllers.js',
     'Scripts/ui-bootstrap-*.js',
     'app/test/controller.test.js'

    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
      'Scripts/angular-scenario.js',
    ],


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'junit', 'growl', 'coverage'
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera (has to be installed with `npm install karma-opera-launcher`)
    // - Safari (only Mac; has to be installed with `npm install karma-safari-launcher`)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows; has to be installed with `npm install karma-ie-launcher`)
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
    captureTimeout: 60000,


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

I don't want to mock anything so far, just to be able to run a single test on my services, but cannot go passed the first beforeEach.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to include `JASMINE` and `JASMINE_ADAPTER` in to the files array like;

```
files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  'Scripts/angular.js',
  'Scripts/angular-mocks.js',
  'Scripts/angular-*.js',
  'Scripts/leaflet.js',
  'app/js/app.js',
  'app/js/services.js',
  'app/js/filters.js',
  'app/js/directives.js',
  'app/js/controllers.js',
  'Scripts/ui-bootstrap-*.js',
  'app/test/controller.test.js'
];
```

Comment: This is depricated now, and has been replaced in Karma config file by 
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

Answer (score 0):

Something isn't getting loaded correctly in your karma.conf.js file

Is this the correct name of your AngularJS file?

```
'Scripts/angular-*.js'
```

I would recommend using regex to load all your JS (this may be unrelated to the problem).

```
'app/scripts/*.js',
'app/scripts/**/*.js'
```

Finally, make sure all the components you have in app.js are loaded in your karma.conf.js file. You have:

tufreport.filters', 'tufreport.services', 'tufreport.directives', 'tufreport.controllers', 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.directives', 'ui.bootstrap'

Each one of these needs a path defined in karma.conf.js for it be loaded correctly for the tests.

Answer (score 0):

1.Try to replace files:[] block of your karma.config.js

```
files: [
     'Scripts/angular.js',
     'Scripts/angular-mocks.js',
     'Scripts/angular-*.js',
     'Scripts/leaflet.js',
     'app/js/services.js',
     'app/js/filters.js',
     'app/js/directives.js',
     'app/js/controllers.js',
     'app/js/app.js',
     'Scripts/ui-bootstrap-*.js',
     'app/test/controller.test.js'

    ],
```

2.inside app.js

```
angular.module('tufreport', ['tufreport.filters', 'tufreport.services', 'tufreport.directives', 'tufreport.controllers',
 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.directives', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```